# How to change the data type of a Sharepoint Column from number to datetime?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint 2010 list which has a column of type "Number" how do I change the data type to DateTime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Number` and `Datetime` fields are quite different and directly switching from number to date via web interface is not allowed. 
However, you can first change number->text and then text->date. (Of course, you may lose your data during conversation)

Comment: Thanks ...I didn't have to worry about data loss as the list was an empty one!

Answer (score 0):

In the ribbon..follow the path as shown below

ListTools-->List---->List Settings-->Columns--->Click on "Your column name"-->Selct date time in "The type of information in this column is" radio button-->Additionally (Date time format under description if needed)--->Click Ok

Comment: radio option 'date and time' not available for 'number' field